# Parse custom log file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

HI have large custom iis log file which i need to parse and store it in json format.

```
 ----------------------------------------
3/27/2017 5:32:54 AM host1

Message: Membership Service Initialization Time: 2296 milliseconds

Severity: Error

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
3/27/2017 5:33:00 AM host1

Message: <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Configuration evaluation context not found.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/services.membership2.0-1-131350663703668815</AppDomain></TraceRecord>

Severity: Warning

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
3/27/2017 5:33:00 AM host2

Message: <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-</TraceRecord>

Severity: Warning

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
3/27/2017 5:33:01 AM host2

Message: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06550: line 1, column 45:
PLS-00302: component 'SP_GET_MEMBER_AND_ROLES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:


Severity: Error

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
3/27/2017 5:45:26 AM host

Message: Membership Service Initialization Time: 1742 milliseconds

Severity: Error

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
```

Basically looking to create -json fomat

{ data: '', time :'', host: '', err_msg :'', servertiy: ''}

how to break file?

Comment: `file.read().split('----------------------------------------\n----------------------------------------')` Or something like that?

Comment: IMHO, you should read the file line by line and implement a custom parser in Python. Easy to write and maintain, and low load on the system whatever the size of log file because you process it line by line. But it is just **my** opinion

Comment: Split is ok, but if I do file.read() it will take up the memory. as File size is huge.

Answer (score 0):

The below code logic breaks the file into list of dictionaries, where each dictionary can be converted to a json object.

```
lst = []

with open('input.txt') as f:

    d = {}
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '---------' in line or '\n' == line:
            continue
        line = line.rstrip('\n')

        if line.startswith('Message:'):
            d['err_msg'] = line[len('Message: '):]
            continue

        if line.startswith('Severity:'):
            d['severity'] = line[len('Severity: '):]
            lst.append(d)
            d = {}
            continue

        line = line.split()
        d['date'] = line[0]
        d['time'] = line[1] + ' ' + line[2]
        d['host'] = line[3]


for l in lst:
    print l
```

And the output is

{'date': '3/27/2017', 'host': 'host1', 'err_msg': 'Membership Service Initialization Time: 2296 milliseconds', 'severity': 'Error', 'time': '5:32:54 AM'}

{'date': '3/27/2017', 'host': 'host1', 'err_msg': 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspxConfiguration evaluation context not found./LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/services.membership2.0-1-131350663703668815', 'severity': 'Warning', 'time': '5:33:00 AM'}

{'date': '3/27/2017', 'host': 'host2', 'err_msg': 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-', 'severity': 'Warning', 'time': '5:33:00 AM'}

{'date': '3/27/2017', 'host': 'host2', 'err_msg': "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06550: line 1, column 45:PLS-00302: component 'SP_GET_MEMBER_AND_ROLES' must be declaredORA-06550: line 1, column 7:", 'severity': 'Error', 'time': '5:33:01 AM'}

{'date': '3/27/2017', 'host': 'host', 'err_msg': 'Membership Service Initialization Time: 1742 milliseconds', 'severity': 'Error', 'time': '5:45:26 AM'}

**Note**: assumed that message is a single line.